# Como imprimir fração no formato de ponto flutuante?

Tags: c++, matemática

Como posso imprimir fração no formato flutuante em C++? Pesquisei como seria esse formato, mas não encontrei nada. E.g :

5

__

3

Comment: 5 sobre 3 é o mesmo que 5.0 / 3.0 (o ponto decimal é para forçar o tratamento como flutuante). Se puser apenas 5/3 vai ser considerado inteiro.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.

Comment: Se o problema for só esse, poste a solução no campo abaixo (de respostas) e marque como aceita (com o V verdinho ao lado dos pontos) para fechar o assunto aqui no site. Não postei como resposta pois não sei se é só essa a sua dúvida.

Comment: É sim, só tenho que converter os valores de inteiros para flutuante e tratar o número de casas em C ++, então eu posto abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Solução

```
std::cout.unsetf(std::ios::floatfield);

std::cout.precision(2);

std::cout << "\n\033[36mFração\033[37m : " << static_cast< float >(this->numerador) << " \033[31m-\033[37m " << static_cast< float >(this->denominador) << "\n";
```